# The dash comes to Telegram as Unicode &#8211; (wp site)

Tags: php, wordpress, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

From my site on WP i send to Telegram chat new posts, I use `get_the_title()`, but if in the title have dash " `-` " in Telegram chat this displayed as `&#8211`;
How this fix?

Answer (score 0):

It is HTML entity. You can use [`html_entity_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to unescape it.

```php
echo html_entity_decode('&#8211;'); // outputs "–"
```

Comment: but my "-" in function get_the_title(), which return "text &#8211; text text", how to be in this situation? @Jax-p

Comment: `html_entity_decode(get_the_title())`

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't help

Comment: So it escapes somewhere else. You gotta find it